# Is is OK to reject an edit based on poor spelling in Edit Summary?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, spelling, grammar

I must get up to 5 or 6 of my daily Suggested Edits that have the following as Edit Summary:

> Fix bad *grammer* [sic]

Maybe I'm just a spelling/grammar/syntax Nazi, but it makes me angry that people who are supposedly improving the grammar of a post can't write 3 words without making a blatant error.

Is it OK to not even give a glance to the actual changes and reject the edit solely based on badly spelled Edit Summary?

Comment: I am a proud grammar Nazi and this drives me *mental*. If it is a short edit and is obvious what has changed then maybe, *maybe* I will read it but if someone can't get that right then I usually dismiss the rest of their work.

Comment: Why would someone attempting to correct the sorry state of the former *Frasier* star upset you so?

Comment: @Shog9 It took me a minute but I guffawed.

Comment: @Shog9 touché! :-)

Comment: @Shog9: problem is, that's *still* bad grammar: as a proper noun, it should be "Grammer".

Comment: There's also a terrible lack of punctuation. Indeed, it's almost as though someone just hammered out a terse answer to an unstated question.

Comment: Related (regarding the much more serious situation of edit summaries that are totally useless, even compared to the automatically generated one): [What to do about good suggested edits with very bad summaries?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3502/what-to-do-about-good-suggested-edits-with-very-bad-summaries)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'd say, no that's not ok.

Sure, poor grammar in the edit summary might be cause for concern that the edit itself is poor, but it is far from a guarantee that that's the case. It's not fair to dismiss an edit without even a glance, if all you are basing your opinion on is the comment.

Instead, evaluate the edit on its own merits. That's all that really counts in the end: 99.99% of users will never see the edit comment, so if that's the *only* place that's of questionable quality then that's not a big problem.

Bottom line: if the **edit itself** is a good edit, approve it - there's **no excuse** for rejecting a good edit, and "I didn't even look at it" **really** doesn't cut it.

Comment: If I had two upvotes to give they would be yours sir.

Comment: Ok... Now, is there a way to communicate to the editor that their spelling of grammar (or whatever crime against the English language they perpetrated) is wrong and that they should be mindful of reviewers' eyes in the future?

Comment: @Joce After their edit you can use the '@' in a comment so they get a notification in their inbox. A little red circle should appear.